# Bind ng-repeat to a promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I'm trying to bind a $resource promise to ng-repeat. But I can't make it work.

The HTML

```
<ul ng-controller="ColorsCtrl">
   <li ng-repeat="colors in getColors()"></li>
</ul>
```

The Script

```
app.module("myApp", ['ngResource'])

.factory('Color', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/colors.json');
})

.controller('ColorsCtrl', function($scope, Color) {
    $scope.getColors = function() {
       return Color.query();
    }
});
```

Comment: Make sure ***not*** to bind to expressions like `colors in getColors()` and go with Matias' answer below. Reason being Angular is aware that ng-repeat is not very performant, so it attempts to cache the property bound.  The problem with using a method like `getColors()` is every time `$scope.$apply` runs, it will fire off that method. This will prevent any caching. I have personally run into issues with this, so just a heads up. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to bind your UI to a promise: you bind the UI to an array, then you fill the array:

```
$scope.colors = [];

var colors = Colors.query(function() {
   // fill here $scope.colors
});
```

While asynchronous request is being processed, usually you show a loading orb in the place where the data is going to be displayed.

Comment: @Jasper You're welcome. After all, this is the way to go. It's about re-thinking everything so it goes well with data-binding :)