# Use $http.get to obtain value of a select

Tags: angularjs

AngularJs(1). I have 2 HTML selects. Each select uses the values from an ajax call ($http.get)

First:

```
<option ng-repeat="lab in getLabels('A')" value="{{lab}}">{{lab}}</option>
```

Second:

```
<option ng-repeat="lab in getLabels('X')" value="{{lab}}">{{lab}}</option>
```

the problem is that because of ajax, `getLabels` returns a promise, and not a direct list. How to workaround this problem, knowing that I have to use a **specific parameter** for each of 2 selects?

Here is **[my test pen](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/ZOQoMN?editors=1010)** (where I simulate an ajax call with the "$q" service)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337666/passing-a-promise-into-ngrepeat or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858592/bind-ng-repeat-to-a-promise)

Comment: @ste2425 my problem is that I have a specific parameter for each control, I can't use in controllers constructor...

Comment: So how does `getLabels` looks like?

Comment: please see my tes pen, @Navoneel, I simulate an ajax call with the "$q" service

Answer (score 1):

Do not bind directly. Use a mediator:  (UPDATED!)
Smth like this

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('CartController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);

myApp.directive('initiator', function($q) {
  return {

    link: function($scope, $elem, $attr) {
      var param = $attr.param;
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var promise = deferred.promise;
      $scope.list = {};

      var labels = [];
      if (param == "A") {
        labels.push("pervii");
        labels.push("first");
      } else if (param == "X") {
        labels.push("poslednii");
        labels.push("last");
        labels.push("dernier");
      } else {
        labels.push("middle");
        labels.push("srednii");
        labels.push("moyen");
      }

      deferred.resolve(labels);
      promise.then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.list[param] = data;
      });

    }
  }
});

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="CartController">
    <select ng-model="label3" initiator param="A">
      <option ng-repeat="lab in list['A']" >{{lab}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited the OP... I have parameters specific for each select, a key to load the resource, so I should specify in each select the key, not possible a priori in controller's constructor...

Comment: Where does your key come from?  From user?

Comment: the page is buld with .NET razor, so the server builds the ng-repeat and gives the key in the html

Comment: Ok. Ill not propose to build select on server side :) So, if I understand you right, that you need this keys at your controller (to make a propper responce) but only your View knows this keys. Am i right?

Comment: tak tochno... my html control (select) should say to the controller the key to load its items

Comment: You can achive this using embedded service + plus razor.
Smth like this. 

Index.cshtml: 

angular.module('app').service('myServerData', function(){
this.myServerData = '@Html.GetJson(Model.Data)';
} );

Comment: I don't want to load the items on the server side, I let angular to do it, because without parameters is simple, but with parameters more complicated...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114364/discussion-between-vitalii-and-serge).